# Binding foreign key in Vaadin (EclipseLink)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin and EclipseLink. There are 2 tables, one is *Mail*, second in *Customer*. PK for Customer is customer_id, PK for mail is mail_id.
Table Mail has Customer_id as a foreign key. How do I bind it?
I tried:

```
binder.forField(fkCustomerId)
        .withConverter(new StringToBigDecimalConverter(FormMessages.NUMBERS_ONLY))
        .bind(Mail::getCustomerId, Mail::setCustomerId);
```

Then I checked the Mail-entity class and found

```
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID")
@ManyToOne
private Customer customerId;
```

I checked this page - https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html but there was nothing about fk binding.

Comment: It would be good to add more information about what you want to do. You probably do not want to allow user to edit your primary key directly. It should probably be set based on something else than user input.

Comment: Table Mail contains some mail settings for customers for another application and contains customer_id as a foreign key. EclipseLink mapped it as Customer customerId but I can't bind an object of class Customer, do I need to convert it into something?

Comment: What do you want to do with the customer object? Do you want to show the customer_id value in a label, show a drop down to create new connection or something else?

Comment: Oh yes, I want to show the value in label.

Comment: I thought it would be as simple as: binder.forField(fkCustomerId)
 .bind(Mail::getCustomerId, Mail::setCustomerId); but nope, it doesn't work like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Convert customer ID**

Here I am assuming that ID field on Customer class is called `id` and that it is of type `Long`. This allows you to access that ID field through converter that produces unformatted string presentation. Note that this does not handle `null` value nicely.

```
binder.forField(fkCustomerId)
        .withConverter(Long::valueOf, String::valueOf)
        .bind("customerId.id");
```

**Option 2: Convert customer object**

This example would take Customer object and convert that to desired format for the customer ID field. This allows you to handle `null` values and do more advanced formatting based on state of the whole object.

```
binder.forField(fkCustomerId)
        .withConverter(new CustomerToCustomerIdConverter())
        .bind(Mail::getCustomerId, Mail::setCustomerId);
```

You can omit `convertToModel`result in the converter because you should not be creating customer objects from ID values that user types.

```
public class CustomerToCustomerIdConverter implements Converter<String, Customer> {
    @Override
    public Result<Customer> convertToModel(String s, ValueContext valueContext) {
        return Result.error("not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToPresentation(Customer customer, ValueContext valueContext) {
        return Objects.toString(customer.getCustomerId(), "");
    }
}
```

**TextField style**

In order to setup TextField style, you need to set it to read-only mode. And if you do not want to get the text field border at all then you need to add extra style.

```
TextField fkCustomerId = new TextField();
fkCustomerId.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TEXTFIELD_BORDERLESS);
fkCustomerId.setReadOnly(true);
```